# Regex Pattern for Washington's Driver License?

Tags: java, regex

I need to verify if a string has a pattern.

So, I decided to something like this...

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:[A-Z]{5}[*]?|[A-Z]{4}[*]|[A-Z]{3}[*]{2}|[A-Z]{2}[*]{3}|[A-Z][*]{4})[A-Z][A-Z*]\\d{3}[A-Z\\d]{2}");
```

and later at my method:

```
PATTERN.matcher(s).matches()
```

But so far, I have not succeed.

I know that pattern filters special characters, but is it possible to make a patter to filter strings like this examples?

```
LLLLLFMYYXmb
WOO**JT547KA
WALKECR577DU
```

What I basically want is to allow also *** at the first 5 spaces, that If i have 3 strings I can have ** (in that order) or if I have 4 strings , one * and so on...

Any idea how to do this? or what is wrong with my expression?

EDIT:

The format is based on how the number is constructed, here is a reference.

http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/numbers/dl_us_wa.html

So, the first 5 letters are made from the truncated last name, but last names could be too short and it wont produce 5 characters, so, the missing spaces will get a * until complete 5 characters.

Comment: Didn't get by : What I basically want is to allow also *** at the first 5 spaces, that If i have 3 strings I can have ** (in that order) or if I have 4 strings , one * and so on..., can you post some examples of input/output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall using a US Driver's License from adambullmer. It worked fine,
[I'll leave the link here](https://github.com/adambullmer/USDLRegex). Hope it helps you!

Comment: It has not the exact pattern... but is gets very close